# How to fetch value input from windows form aplication

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}

and


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.num1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.num1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // num1
            // 
            this.num1.AccessibleName = "";
            this.num1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.num1.Name = "num1";
            this.num1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 20);
            this.num1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.num1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.num1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown num1;

    }
}
```

Comment: What you exactly needed was not clear please be specific and let us know regarding what you need

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish? Code is useful, but a description of what you want to do and how you're having trouble would be helpful.

Comment: Now i need to be able to grab input then use it to make a calculator but i don't know how

Comment: So over all you want to do a calculator application

Comment: i wanted to make an interface other than command prompt

Comment: So a pure c# calculator you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public getter function on the Form1 class that accesses the values in the controls you need values from.

Comment: Form1 could have a method like public int GetNum() {return num1.Value;}
But you are better off studying an example.